# how to multiple selected item pass secound activity to 1st activity (only selected items)and stored shared preference

Tags: android, gridview, shared, preference

I am a new Android Developer and I need to pass multiple selected grid view items from one activity to another. Then selected items stored in selected order and using shared preference.
 Please help me.

my second activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
ArrayList<String> resultArr;
Button add, exit;
GridView grid;
baseadapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resultArr = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.main_grid);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    if (resultArr != null) {
        adapter = new baseadapter();
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resultArr.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

class baseadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return resultArr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.base, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageResource(ListActivity.image_items[Integer.parseInt(resultArr.get(position))]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

}

My another activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
ArrayList<String> resultArr;
Button add, exit;
GridView grid;
baseadapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resultArr = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.main_grid);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    if (resultArr != null) {
        adapter = new baseadapter();
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            resultArr.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

class baseadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return resultArr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.base, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageResource(ListActivity.image_items[Integer.parseInt(resultArr.get(position))]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post some code and more detailed explanation

Comment: i am posted my code please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass few values from one activity to another then you can do that using Bundles. For example, you have two activities Activity A and Activity B and you want to pass then it can be done

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(key, val);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have done this one but i need multiple selected items pass and stored another grid view in another activity(only selected order to listed) using shared preference.

Comment: If you want to do using SharedPreference then you can save the data to SharedPreference when any event occurs such as button click and then in another Activity read the data from SharedPreference in onCreate().